# Can't find Availability.h header file with gcc

Tags: python, xcode, gcc, header, anaconda

When I try to install new python packages with pip, I get the following error. Looks like gcc can't find the Availability.h header file. I've had this problem with multiple python packages so it's not just problem with the library. I'm running Anaconda 2.2.0 and I'm on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 64-bit .

I tried reinstalling Xcode and Xcode dev tools since it appears to be a problem with gcc, but that didn't work.

```html
beavernet-163:desktop David$ pip install bllipparser
Collecting bllipparser
  Using cached bllipparser-2015.01.11.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: bllipparser
  Running setup.py install for bllipparser
    Complete output from command /Users/David/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/0d/n030c4312490_6px0bt47_wh0000gn/T/pip-build-X5SLrE/bllipparser/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/0d/n030c4312490_6px0bt47_wh0000gn/T/pip-FzytLX-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /Users/David/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-14.3-py2.7.egg/setuptools/dist.py:282: UserWarning: Normalizing '2015.01.11' to '2015.1.11'
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/bllipparser
    copying python/bllipparser/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/bllipparser
    copying python/bllipparser/CharniakParser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/bllipparser
    copying python/bllipparser/JohnsonReranker.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/bllipparser
    copying python/bllipparser/ModelFetcher.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/bllipparser
    copying python/bllipparser/ParsingShell.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/bllipparser
    copying python/bllipparser/RerankerFeatureCorpus.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/bllipparser
    copying python/bllipparser/RerankingParser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/bllipparser
    running build_ext
    building 'bllipparser._CharniakParser' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/first-stage
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/first-stage/PARSE
    gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -I/Users/David/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ifirst-stage/PARSE/ -I/Users/David/anaconda/include/python2.7 -c first-stage/PARSE/parser_wrapper.C -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7/first-stage/PARSE/parser_wrapper.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
    In file included from /Users/David/anaconda/include/python2.7/pyport.h:325:0,
                     from /Users/David/anaconda/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                     from first-stage/PARSE/parser_wrapper.C:155:
    /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0/4.8.1/include-fixed/math.h:54:26: fatal error: Availability.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Availability.h>
                              ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/Users/David/anaconda/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/0d/n030c4312490_6px0bt47_wh0000gn/T/pip-build-X5SLrE/bllipparser/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/0d/n030c4312490_6px0bt47_wh0000gn/T/pip-FzytLX-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/0d/n030c4312490_6px0bt47_wh0000gn/T/pip-build-X5SLrE/bllipparser
```

Here is the gcc version.

```
beavernet-163:desktop David$ gcc --version
gcc: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘14.1.0
gcc (GCC) 4.8.1
```

And Xcode version is 6.2.

Comment: Are you getting this error building other Python packages which need to be compiled as well?